# When we run this code , we see additional ciphers other than the ones mentioned.How do we force enable specific ciphers only?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

pprint.pprint(context.get_ciphers()) prints additional ciphers too. How do we force the usage of ciphers and extensions ?

```
import socket, ssl
import pprint
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
CIPHERS ="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CBC-SHA:RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:RSA-AES128-CBC-SHA:RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:AES:256-GCM-SHA384"
context.set_ciphers(CIPHERS)
pprint.pprint(context.get_ciphers())
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
domain = 'google.com'
sslSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = domain)
sslSocket.connect((domain, 443))
#context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2
#context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
print(sslSocket.cipher())
print(sslSocket.version())
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
sslSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is unclear what ciphers you exactly mean with "we see additional ciphers other than the ones mentioned" you likely mean TLS 1.3 ciphers like `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. From [the documentation of set_ciphers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers):

> OpenSSL 1.1.1 has TLS 1.3 cipher suites enabled by default. The suites cannot be disabled with set_ciphers().

If you want to disable TLS 1.3 ciphers you have to disable TLS 1.3:

```
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3
```

Note that this does not actually remove the ciphers from the output of `get_ciphers` but it makes these unusable. To actually set these ciphers one would need to call the OpenSSL API [SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html). This API is [not yet available](https://bugs.python.org/issue33570) from Python.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to exclude a specific cipher. lets say I want to exclude ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384
I have been trying to exclude it using ! at the of the cipher list. Adding ! works for some ciphers and not for some making me feel its being over written/added.
I want to use python to support exactly 19 specific ciphers but I have not been able to exclude the below ciphers
TLS-ECDHE-AES256-CBC-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CBC-SHA256
RSA-AES256-CCM8
RSA-AES256-CCM
RSA-AES128-CCM8

Comment: @aqua: it would have been helpful if your question contained this information, instead of letting other second guess what you exactly mean with *"additional ciphers"*. Apart from that you explicitly include "AES" as the second last item in your cipher string and thus include all AES based ciphers. If you want to have 19 specific ciphers then only specify these ciphers and nothing else.

Comment: Sorry Ulrich, I have only been a reader here and have not been posting a lot of questions. Adding more details now:
I changed my cipher now   and specifically excluded ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384 in this cipher list but my pcap still has this cipher now. same thing with ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384.
In addition ,I also did !PSK:!AECDH:!ADH:!DSS:!CCM:!DHE:!SRP but the ciphers containing CCM did not get excluded. so had to use ! for negating every cipher I did not need.
! ciphers worked for some and did not work for few.

Comment: @aqua: You have only fragments of what you are doing in your comment. But to actually understand and reproduce what you are doing I need the __exact__ code you are using and a description what you expect to see and what you see instead.  You might use pastebin.com for the code so that it does not get garbled when you write it in a comment. In this case please also add your expectations and what you get instead as comments to the code.